# Getting the last word of an NSString

Tags: objective-c, ios

As the title suggests, I would like to get the last word out of an NSString.
I thought using this code:

```
NSArray *listItems = [someNSStringHere componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
NSString *lastWordString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", listItems.lastObject];
anotherNSStringHere = lastWordString;
```

But I think the NSArray will take a time to load if it's big (and it is big), and it wouldn't recognize a word separated by a comma.

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you want to be super-robust:

```
__block NSString *lastWord = nil;

[someNSStringHere enumerateSubstringsInRange:NSMakeRange(0, [someNSStringHere length]) options:NSStringEnumerationByWords | NSStringEnumerationReverse usingBlock:^(NSString *substring, NSRange subrange, NSRange enclosingRange, BOOL *stop) {
    lastWord = substring;
    *stop = YES;
}];
```

(This should also work with non-Roman languages; iOS 4+/OS X 10.6+.)

Basic explanation:

`-enumerateSubstringsInRage:options:usingBlock:` does what it says on the tin: it enumerates substrings, which are defined by what you pass in as the options. `NSStringEnumerationByWords` says "I want words given to me", and `NSStringEnumerationReverse` says "start at the end of the string instead of the beginning".

Since we're starting from the end, the first word given to us in `substring` will be the last word in the string, so we set `lastWord` to that, and then set the `BOOL` pointed to by `stop` to YES, so the enumeration stops right away.

`lastWord` is of course defined as `__block` so we can set it inside the block and see it outside, and it's initialized to `nil` so if the string *has* no words (e.g., if it's empty or is all punctuation) we don't crash when we try to use `lastWord`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your explaination!

Comment: Nice solution. Add the `NSStringEnumerationLocalized` option (take into account current user locale for word separation) if you want to be super-extra-robust. ;-)

Answer (score 12):

Give this a try:

```
NSRange range = [someNSStringHere rangeOfString:@" " options:NSBackwardsSearch];
NSString *result = [someNSStringHere substringFromIndex:range.location+1];
```

Comment: I agree. Start from the end, one character at a time, until you reach a space, comma or any other delimiter you can foresee.

Comment: If `@" "` is not found, you may want to use the full string instead. I'd do this: `NSRange range = [someString rangeOfString:@" " options:NSBackwardsSearch]; NSString *lastWord = someString; if (range.location != NSNotFound) { lastWord = [self substringFromIndex:range.location+1]; }`.

Answer (score 3):

If you wanted to use a regular expression (which can be useful if you want to start getting more complicated in terms of what you're looking for at the end of your string), you could do something like:

```
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\\S+\\Z" options:0 error:nil];
NSTextCheckingResult *found = [regex firstMatchInString:inputString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [inputString length])];

if (found.range.location != NSNotFound)
    result = [inputString substringWithRange:found.range];
```

Answer (score 3):

That works great as it also recognizes symbols like @ and # which `enumerateSubstringsInRange:` doesn't do.

```
NSCharacterSet *charSet = [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet];
NSArray *components = [someString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:charSet];
NSString *lastWord = components.lastObject;
```

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient way is likely to start at the end of the string, examine each character to see if it's part of what you define as a word, and then extract the word you want using `substringFromIndex:` or `substringWithRange:`.

Answer (score 0):

You can read symbols from the end of the your string and copy them at the 0 index to result string. Whether you read space or comma, result string wil contain the last word

Answer (score 0):

You could use `NSString`'s function `rangeOfSubstring:options:` to determine it. For example:

Search the string for a space, using a backwards search option to start the search from the end of the string.

`NSRange r = [string rangeOfString:@" " options:NSBackwardsSearch];`

This will find the location of the last word of the string. Now just get the string using `substringWithRange:` For Example:

`NSRange found = NSMakeRange(NSMaxRange(r), string.length - NSMaxRange(r));
    NSString *foundString = [string substringWithRange:found];`

Where `r` is the range from earlier.

Also be careful to make sure that you check `r` actually exists. If there is only 1 word in the string, then `r` will be `{NSNotFound, 0}`

Hope I could help!

Ben